# Circular Dependencies in 3NF

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

I have a table:

Customer(**username**, firstName, lastName, age, gender, race)

**username** determines firstName, lastName, age, gender, race.

firstName, lastName can be used to uniquely identify a row in the table, so firstName, lastName determines **username**, age, gender, race.

Is the table in 3NF because some non-prime attributes (firstName, lastName) can be used to determine other attributes in the table, but the PK (**username**) can determine the non-prime attributes that are then used to determine other attributes?

This is not in BCNF because of that circular dependency.

Comment: *"some non-prime attributes (firstName, lastName)"* Those are prime attributes.

Comment: One doesn't work with databases too long to learn that (FirstName, LastName) isn't even close to a candidate key. Wait til you hit your second "Joe Smith" or "Sally Jones" or "John Brown" and you'll learn it real fast.

Comment: I was using it as an example. My database has a CK that is something like firstName, lastName, phoneNumber. I was trying to think of a hypothetical circumstance that would suffice for my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Circularities are irrelevant, and it's in BCNF, and every lower NF. A definition for BCNF is, all the determinants of non-trivial FDs are superkeys. If there are multiple CKs (candidate keys), so be it. The CKs will detemine the attributes of other CKs, because a CK determines every attribute.

PKs are irrelevant to normalization (and all other relational theory), CKs matter. A PK is just a CK you decided to call a PK.

There are two CKs here, {username} and {firstName, lastName}. The prime attributes, ie those in the CKs, are username, firstName & lastName.